# HARDHAT - Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, blockchain, hardhat

```
Error: error: 0308010 C: digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash(node: internal / crypto / hash: 67: 19)
at Object.createHash(node: crypto: 130: 10)
at hash160(D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ ethereum - cryptography\ vendor\ hdkey - without - crypto.js: 249: 21)
at HDKey.set(D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ ethereum - cryptography\ vendor\ hdkey - without - crypto.js: 50: 24)
at Function.HDKey.fromMasterSeed(D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ ethereum - cryptography\ vendor\ hdkey - without - crypto.js: 194: 20)
at deriveKeyFromMnemonicAndPath(D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ hardhat\ src\ internal\ util\ keys - derivation.ts: 22: 27)
at derivePrivateKeys(D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ hardhat\ src\ internal\ core\ providers\ util.ts: 30: 52)
at normalizeHardhatNetworkAccountsConfig(D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ hardhat\ src\ internal\ core\ providers\ util.ts: 58: 10)
at createProvider(D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ hardhat\ src\ internal\ core\ providers\ construction.ts: 79: 59)
at D: \buildspace\ my - wave - portal\ node_modules\ hardhat\ src\ internal\ core\ runtime - environment.ts: 80: 28 {
  opensslErrorStack: ['error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error'],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I have been trying to run hardhat on my windows. After setting up hardhat .. when i try to run following commands - "npx hardhat accounts or npx hardhat test" , I get the error given above

I already tried downgrading node version and tried setting node options. When i set node options , I get this error - --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS. I'm running this on windows

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider including the relevant parts of the code as well as what you're doing.

Comment: There's no extra code. I have been trying to run hardhat on my windows. After setting up hardhat .. when i try to run following commands - "npx hardhat accounts or npx hardhat test" , I get the error given above

Answer (score 2):

try executing this before: export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider